# Can't access site collection with any account

Tags: sharepoint

I have a strange problem.
I'm working on a site collection http://mydomain/sites/cb belong to content database WSS_DB
It work fine until yesterday. Then I can't suddently access this site
The other site of same content DB are still fine.
The whole other sites are still fine.
When I use firefox to access it just show message "The connection was reset"
but chrome ask me to login but i try all account: domain account, system account...
I also can't access with IE at sharepoint server
I also can't access http://mydomain/sites/CB/Pages/default.aspx?ToolPaneView=2
But I still can open site by sharepoint design 2013
I still can access Web part maintain page of default page of site collection
http://mydomain/sites/CB/Pages/default.aspx?contents=1

I have full controll of Sharepoint server, DB server, farm, site collection

What I have try:
- Disable loop back check at sharepoint server
- Reset IIS, reset server (SP and DB)
- Dismount then remount db content
- Checked user permission and user policy at , it's all fine
- I don't find any useful info in log file
- The last things i do when the site can access are:
+ Edit web part in a page, save then publish
+ At Sharepoint designer: i copy a page to another folder

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: any help or suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure myself.Here how i solve my problem

- 1 item of my list is contain wrong data, it make a infinite recursion, when my webpart browser the list, it cant finish
- Just reinput the item then problem gone.